# Adding Tablesorter(Mottie fork) to Drupal 7 project

Tags: drupal-7, fork, drupal-modules, tablesorter

I am currently using [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/tablesorter) Tablesorter module in Drupal 7. The functionality is very limited compared to the [Mottie fork](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) of Tablesorter. Is it possible to just swap all the files from the Mottie fork into the current module directory (not touching the original .info or .module files themselves)?

In short, What's the recommended way to add Tablesorter(fork) to a drupal 7 project?